# ControlValueAccessor isn't updating origin Control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**Edit:** rephrased for clarification.

In my app I am dynamicly building the forms from a JSON fetched from Backend.

When the JSON has a "password" field I would like- instead of showing single password input field- to display 2 fields: one for password and one for password confirmation.

To this purpose, I created a custom component implementing ControlValueAccessor.

My goal is to set the original password control's error state (and value) based on my custom component.

**What I've tried:**
I have a working implementation of ControlValueAccessor that successfully reflects the changes to the origin control, i.e.:

```js
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <custom-input-working [formControlName]="atext"></custom-input-working>
</form>
```

where `form` and `atext` are defined as follows:

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({"atext": ['', Validators.required]})
```

and `custom-input-working` is defined with:

```js
export abstract class AbstractValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
    protected control = new FormControl();

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        if(obj != undefined && obj != null) {
            this.control.setValue(obj);
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    }

}
```

But when I try to replace the template with some more complicated structure (i.e.: 2 fields) the functionality breaks.

```js
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <custom-password [formControlName]="password"></custom-password>
</form>

this.form = this.fb.group({password: ['', Validators.required]})



@Component({
selector: 'custom-password',
template: `<form [formGroup]="form">
             <input type="password" formControlName="passwordInput">
             <input type="password" formControlName="passwordConfirm">
           <form>`
providers: [/*The NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR thing */]
})
export class PasswordComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
/* ... */

control:FormControl = new FormControl();

constructor(/*...*/){
    this.form.get("passwords").valueChanges.subsscribe(x => {
        this.writeValue(x.passwordInput); // <---- this writeValue() [line 56 in plunkr] is where I expect the origin control to be updated, as happens in the working example. Obviously I'm wrong here.
        if(x.passwordInput !== x.confirmPassword){
            this.control.setErrors({"passwordConfirm": true}); // <--- again, this probably doesn't set the error on origin control [line 58]
        }
    })
}
}
```

The original control ("password") doesn't get the "passwordInput" value, and it isn't getting the errors as well.

**What I have also tried:**
Binding directly to "control":

```html
<input type="password" [formControl]="control">
```

Here is my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VAVg0TmlHbIbXM4bzJzD?p=preview

At the bottom- the working solution. At the top- where I fail.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could include your validation logic to show how you are trying to validate in the first place since that is the issue at hand.

Comment: It is not only the validation (line 55 on plunkr) but the value itself that is not propagated to the original control (as opposed to the working example).

Comment: You have two different references to FormControl